# Change working directory path make error to run my program

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a project whose **Project Settings > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Working directory** is set to **$(ProjectDir)**  but i was just playing with the visual studio for my learning i change it to something like C:\opencv\2.4.4 and now when i upload that project i give me the below error and can't upload

[image]

How i can change it back to the right form which was like `$(ProjectDir)`

Comment: The same way you changed it the first time round. Just enter the text `$(ProjectDir)` in the edit box for this setting.

Comment: but now its not giving the option of properties and its not even loading

Comment: Interesting. I'd try opening .vcproj file in a text editor (it's just a text file), then searching for and replacing that string. At least you should be able to get the project file to the point where the IDE can open it.